# Using Partial Fraction Decomposition to acquire appropriate form for GCIF

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I need to find the PFD so I may continue with a complex integral $\int_C \frac{ze^z}{z^6 - 1}dz$, $z \in \mathbb{C}$. The contour $C = |z-a|=a$, $a>0$

I have found all $6$ roots of $z^6 - 1$, so would I write it as

$\frac{1}{(z-z_0)(z-z_1)(z-z_2)(z-z_3)(z-z_4)(z-z_5)} = \frac{A}{(z-z_0)} + \cdots + \frac{E}{(z-z_5)}$

Then once I multiply through and group the terms appropriately, would all of the constant terms together be equal to $1$? This just seems a tad messy and I am wondering if there is just a quick way to do this.

Once I get my PFD, I can continue with the Generalized Cauchy Integral formula and be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since
$$
z^6-1=(z-1)(z+1)(z-w)(z+w)(z-\bar{w})(z+\bar{w}), \quad w=e^{i\frac\pi3}
$$
we have
$$
\frac{1}{(z-1)(z+1)(z-w)(z+w)(z-\bar{w})(z+\bar{w})}=\frac{A_1}{z-1}+\frac{A_2}{z+1}+\frac{A_3}{z-w}+\frac{A_4}{z+w}+\frac{A_5}{z-\bar{w}}+\frac{A_6}{z+\bar{w}}
$$
Multiplying the two sides of the previous identity by $z-1$ we have
$$
\frac{z-1}{z^6-1}=A_1+(z-1)\left[\frac{A_2}{z+1}+\frac{A_3}{z-w}+\frac{A_4}{z+w}+\frac{A_5}{z-\bar{w}}+\frac{A_6}{z+\bar{w}}\right]
$$
and letting $z\to1$ we get 
$$
A_1=\frac{1}{(z^6-1)'}\Big|_{z=1}=\frac16.
$$
Similarly we get
\begin{eqnarray}
A_2&=&\frac{1}{(z^6-1)'}\Big|_{z=-1}=-\frac16\\
A_3&=&\frac{1}{(z^6-1)'}\Big|_{z=w}=\frac{1}{6w^5}=\frac{w}{6}\\
A_4&=&\frac{1}{(z^6-1)'}\Big|_{z=-w}=\frac{1}{-6w^5}=-\frac{w}{6}\\
A_5&=&\frac{1}{(z^6-1)'}\Big|_{z=\bar{w}}=\frac{1}{6\bar{w}^5}=\frac{\bar{w}}{6}\\
A_6&=&\frac{1}{(z^6-1)'}\Big|_{z=-\bar{w}}=\frac{1}{-6\bar{w}^5}=-\frac{\bar{w}}{6}
\end{eqnarray}
Hence
$$
\frac{1}{z^6-1}=\frac16\left[\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{z+1}+w\left(\frac{1}{z-w}-\frac{1}{z+w}\right)+\bar{w}\left(\frac{1}{z-\bar{w}}-\frac{1}{z+\bar{w}}\right)\right]
$$